# Отследить изменения состояния страницы с помощью webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть сайт, в котором в одном из фреймов периодически возникают события, т.е. страничка полностью перерисовывается и там появляется отличный от предыдущего контент. Как это событие можно словить? И можно ли как-то различать, какое именно событие произошло?

Comment: Например, можно разобраться во внутренней логике страницы, посылать на сервер нужные запросы аяксом и правильно интерпретировать ответы.

Comment: К сожалению в аякс запросах я ноль. В логике странице разбираюсь, но события, которые возникают во фрейме от меня не зависят. Они могут возникнуть в любой момент времени, мне лишь нужно программно перехватить его и уже делать нужные вещи с ним.

Comment: может, как вариант сделать инъекцию javascript- повесить свое событие на onload фрейма и в коде сделать обработчик в случае его возникновения. такое не делал, но думаю реально. про события http://javascript.info/tutorial/frames-and-iframes про обработчик события http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167522/how-to-handle-javascript-events-via-webbrowser-control-for-winforms про инъекцию javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control. попробуй, должно получится

Comment: Есть еще способы попроще ?)